# Has this generalization of Turing machines studied before?

Tags: turing-machines, reference-request

### Introduction

Hello, I'm designing a generalized model of Turing machines for a formalization in [MIZAR](http://mizar.org/). Mizar needs some concrete objects to work with, so I spent some time figuring out how the "tape" of a Turing machine could be defined since that part is usually left out when introducing Turing machines.
After some thinking I concluded it would be best to use graphs, so I define a "Turing Space" $T$ as a function from an cardinal $C$ to graphs. A position $p$ in the Turing Space is then defined as a function from the cardinal into the vertex sets of these graphs, so that for $c\in C$, $p.c$ is a vertex of $T.c$. From this basis one can built transition functions and so forth.

### Examples

Given a double ray (a path graph that is infinite in both directions) $R$ and a positive integer $k$, the function $f_k:k\ni i\mapsto R$ (defined on $\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$) would be a Turing space describing the bands of a $k$-band TM.
Given a positive integer $d$, set $E_d:=\{\{a,b\}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^d,\sum|a_i-b_i|=1\}$ and graph $G_d=(\mathbb{Z}^d, E_d)$, this is the grid on $\mathbb{Z}^d$. Now the function $g_d:\{0\}\ni i\mapsto G_d$ describes the hyperspace of a $d$-dimensional TM.
These two examples are of course quite different, as the first has $k$ pointers, that can move in 3 directions (left, right, stay) each, and the second has one pointer that can move in $2d+1$ directions. That they are nevertheless computational equivalent (because they are Turing-complete) is well known. Also both reduce to a simple Turing tape in case of $k=d=1$.
It is easy to see that other well-known tape variants can be described by this definition just as well.

### But it doesn't end there

However, the definition above allows much more complex examples for tapes, most notably when using infinite cardinals. And when I'm about defining Turing machines, I wonder why I would restrict the alphabet and set of states to be finite. Of course, these generalizations make it much more difficult to image any kind of realization in the real world. Nevertheless, I think it is kind of interesting if these generalizations of a TM would make it possible to archive something beyond Turing completeness. Other known generalizations such as non deterministic TMs and quantum TMs do not seem to have archived greater computability. Maybe I missed something?

### The Question

Has my kind of generalization (the different "Turing Spaces") been studied before? Or any kind of allowing infinite states and/or alphabets besides the kind appearing in quantum TMs?

Comment: Your description is too cryptic for me to understand. What is $f_k : k \ni i \mapsto R$ supposed to mean?

Comment: I've no idea what MIZAR is but why can't you just formalize the tape as a finite sequence, as usual?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Has been done already: http://mizar.org/version/current/html/turing_1.html#NM2
It is simply too narrow to capture advanced concepts like $k$-band TMs or $d$-dimensional TMs. And since Mizar is a formalization system, this means the definitions have to be done again and again for these generalized, yet specialized cases. Hence an even more general approach is desirable. At first I thought of connected subsets of the grid of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ to be used as Turing Spaces, but then I realized the important thing are cells and how they are connected. So graphs, yeah.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Sorry for the inconvenience. $f_k$ maps from $k=\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$ (ordinal viewpoint of natural numbers) to the set $\{R\}$, i.e. it is the constant function $f_k\equiv R$. But I thought if I wrote that, the domain would be unclear. Also I thought that the $x \mapsto f(x)$ notation for a function $f$ and an element $x$ from its domain would be commonly known.

Answer (score 3):

A general notion of machines based on graphs was given by Wilfried Sieg and John Byrnes in [K-Graph Machines: Generalizing Turing's Machines and Arguments](http://repository.cmu.edu/philosophy/198/). It may or may not be related to what you are doing.

Also note that it is quite easy to find a complete formalization of Turing machines. Why are you saying that "the tape of a Turing machine ... is usually left out when introducing Turing machines". That's an odd thing to say. Let's perform an experiment. For instance, what is unclear about [the definition given on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition) (following a standard textbook)? All you need is a formalization of finite sequences, and I'd be flabbergasted if Mizar hasn't got those.

Comment: That description doesn't actually talk about the *tape* itself. But as you say, it is not hard to provide a formalization. I recently wrote a symbolic definition of a (alternating) Turing machine and simply represented the tape, for the purposes of defining acceptance, as a function $\mathbb N\to\Gamma$, $\Gamma$ being the set of symbols.

Comment: @DerekElkins When I define the tape as a function from a domain to $\gamma$, then I did not define the tape, but the tape and what's written on it. The tape is represented by the domain. Tying the domain to a specific set may be good for practical cases, but e.g. taking $\mathbb{Z}^d$ could be the domain for both the $d$-dimensional and the $d$-band TM, then I need to make distinction how the head(s) move(s). I'm trying to avoid exactly that: too many distinctions. Instead, I'm trying to create an all-purpose formalization and am just wondering if the new cases appearing have been studied yet.

Comment: I would imagine people have studied every conceivable variant of Turing machine to death, well beyond the point of diminishing returns.

Comment: This is indeed the only source I've found myself that could have something to do with it and I'm still reading it. Thank you anyway. And yes, as @DerekElkins pointed out, the tape itself is not formalized, in contradiction to the 7 objects the TM definition consists of. My point with "left out" isn't that one couldn't think of a formalization of the tape (I think we have 3 in this Q&A already), but that there isn't a canonical one. This is not a bad thing. But it simply isn't in the standard textbooks.

Comment: @SK19 In that case, I would take a more "axiomatic"/"abstract" approach. Instead of trying to pick a "most general" representation, avoid picking *any* representation. For example (just a random idea I thought up just now which is probably terrible), maybe it makes sense to have the transition function return the generators of a group, and the tape is a set acted upon by that group (and it's values are just a function from the set to the alphabet). 1D 1-sided is $\mathbb Z$ acting on $\mathbb N$. 2D is $\langle U,R\mid UR=RU\rangle$ acting on $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$.

Comment: @SK19 My point being instead of making it so that specific examples can be *encoded* into your formalization, make it so that specific examples are *instances* of your formalization.

Comment: @DerekElkins It seems I'm avoiding Group theory too much. Guess I should really read a good book about that again, touched the last one around 2013? In any case, I will remember your suggestion :-)

Comment: @DerekElkins "make it so that specific examples are instances of your formalization" I... guess this is what I'm doing? General formalization, then break it down to the usual cases and get a handy 1-band TM. After that, the formalization of universal TM, decidability and P/NP. Long way to go, but fun :D

Comment: @SK19: the difference between an *abstract* and a *general concrete* approach is that the abstract approach does not prescribe a specific representation. You are fixing the representation of the tapes to involve certain kinds of graphs and maps into them, etc. An abstract approach would not do such a thing. Instead, you'd have an (arbitrary) set $T$ for "tapes" and some operations on $T$ (which may or may not be a group action). In an abstract approach it doesn't matter what $T$ "really is".

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thanks for the clarification, I will think about it.

Comment: I've studied the paper now. It is not what I was looking for, but contained another reference I may have use for.

Comment: @DerekElkins Maybe you or Andrej Bauer can formulize your ideas about this abstraction in my other question? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/how-can-generalized-turing-machine-tapes-be-defined